# Work around Flatpickr input required and fill form with JS bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, bookmarklet, autofill, flatpickr

I’m attempting to speed up a web page form-filling workflow by using a Javascript bookmarklet to auto-fill certain fields. I’ve got everything working except for filling a couple date/time fields which are controlled by Flatpickr. Here is my bookmarklet code, mostly created by FormFillerJS.com:

```
var d=document;
function i(a){
    return d.getElementById(a)}
function n(a){
    return d.getElementsByName(a)[0]}
function e(a){
    t='change';
    if(window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident|MSIEs/g)!=null){
        x=d.createEvent('Events');
        x.initEvent(t,1,0);}
    else{
        x=new Event(t);}
    a.dispatchEvent(x);}
function v(a,v){
    a.value=v;e(a)}
function c(a){
    a.checked=true;e(a)}
v(i("start-date"),"2018-10-17 11:30");
v(i("end-date"),"2018-10-17 13:30");
v(n("campus"),"1");
v(i("payroll_addendum_category"),"4");
v(i("payroll_addendum_rate"),"Faculty Rate");
v(i("payroll_addendum_course"),"319");
v(i("payroll_addendum_requested_by"),"John Doe");
v(i("notes"),"My note");
void(0);
```

These two lines…

```
v(i("start-date"),"2018-10-17 11:30");
v(i("end-date"),"2018-10-17 13:30");
```

…are not filling at all. I’m a total newbie at this, but my impression is that Flatpickr has to be invoked somehow. Is there any way to do this with a JS bookmarklet, or am I stuck manually picking the date/time with the Flatpickr interface?

If it helps, here is the source I’m seeing around these two fields:

```
<div class="input-label"><input id="start-date" type="hidden" class="required placeholder flatpickr-input" name="start_date" placeholder="Start Date/Time" value="" data-name="my-payroll-create"><input class="required placeholder flatpickr-input flatpickr-mobile" step="any" type="datetime-local" placeholder="Start Date/Time" min="2018-09-18"><input class="required placeholder flatpickr-input form-control input" placeholder="Start Date/Time" type="hidden" readonly="readonly"><div class="placeholder-label">Start Date/Time</div></div></div>
            <div><div class="input-label"><input id="end-date" type="hidden" class="required flatpickr-input" name="end_date" placeholder="End Date/Time" value="" data-name="my-payroll-create"><input class="required flatpickr-input flatpickr-mobile placeholder" step="any" type="datetime-local" placeholder="End Date/Time" min="2018-09-18"><input class="required flatpickr-input form-control input" placeholder="End Date/Time" type="hidden" readonly="readonly"><div class="placeholder-label">End Date/Time</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that instead of your lines:

```
v(i("start-date"),"2018-10-17 11:30");
v(i("end-date"),"2018-10-17 13:30");
```

you should use something like these:

```
i("start-date")._flatpickr.setDate("2018-10-17 11:30", true);
i("end-date")._flatpickr.setDate("2018-10-17 13:30", true);
```

Hope it will be helpful.


(For more details see the documentation on [Flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org).)

Comment: Thank you for the response, Shugar! I tried the lines exactly as you described (and in any variations I could think of). Unfortunately, I still can’t get it to work. I’m using iOS Shortcuts to test the script on the webpage, and when I run those lines as you typed it, it gives me the following error: “TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘i("start-date")._flatpickr.setDate’)”. I wish that the Flatpickr documentation helped me a lot, but I just can’t make sense of it with my extremely limited knowledge of JS.

Comment: OK, let's follow my way. (1) Go to the [flatpickr Date Time example](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#datetime). (2) Try this code: `document.querySelector("input[data-id='datetime']")._flatpickr.setDate("2018-10-17 11:30", true);` Is it alright?

Comment: Well, it turns out, perhaps using iOS Shortcuts to test this was a mistake, and I apologize for wasting any of your time! The bookmarklet code as you originally suggested works perfectly, as does the example code in your comment above. For flexibility, I was kind of hoping to use Shortcuts to implement the form-filler rather than the bookmarklet (to execute things like auto-filling in the date/time based on items in my calendar). Any guesses as to why a Shortcut running from the Share Sheet extension might throw that TypeError, while a bookmarklet works just fine?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software mentioned above. Maybe it requires `window.document` instead of `document` - have no idea. BTW, in case of more complex web automation I prefer using the 'iMacros for Chrome' (or 'iMacros for Firefox') free extension.

Comment: I’ll have to check out iMacros, thanks! And I’ll try `window.document`, too. Thank you so much for your help. I’ll also pitch this issue to https://reddit.com/r/shortcuts, which deals with that particular piece of software that I mentioned.